# ReadCSVfile error

Tags: c#, csv

I've this code

```
    class Player
{
    private string first_name;
    private string middle_name;
    private string last_name;
    private DateTime dob;
    private string nat;
    private char gender;
    public Player(string first_name, string last_name, string middle_name, DateTime dob, string nat, char gender)
    {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.middle_name = middle_name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.nat = nat;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return first_name + " " + middle_name + " " + last_name + " " + dob + " " + nat + " " + gender;
    }
    private List<string> content = new List<string>();
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Delimiter { get; set; }
    public ReadCSVFile(string fn, string delim = "|")
    {
        FileName = fn;
        Delimiter = delim;
    }
    public void Load()
    {
        TextFieldParser par = new TextFieldParser(FileName);
        par.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        par.SetDelimiters(Delimiter);
        while (!par.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = par.ReadFields();
            foreach (string field in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(field);
            }
        }
        par.Close();
    }
    static void RunReadCSVFile()
    {
        var f = new ReadCSVFile(@"C:\Temp\car1.txt");
        f.Load();
    }
```

It's after the ToString method I have a problem. I get an error when i try to create the method ReadCSVFile. The IDE says that "method must have a return value". However, I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class Player
    {

    private string first_name;
    private string middle_name;
    private string last_name;
    private DateTime dob;
    private string nat;
    private char gender;

    public Player(string first_name, string last_name, string middle_name, DateTime dob, string nat, char gender)
    {
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.middle_name = middle_name;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.nat = nat;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return first_name + " " + middle_name + " " + last_name + " " + dob + " " + nat + " " + gender;
    }

   private List<string> content = new List<string>();
   public string FileName { get; set; }
   public string Delimiter { get; set; }

   //public static class ReadCSVFile(string fn, string delim = "|")
   //{
   //    FileName = fn;
   //    Delimiter = delim;
   //}

   private void Load()
   {
       TextFieldParser par = new TextFieldParser(FileName);
       par.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
       par.SetDelimiters(Delimiter);
       while (!par.EndOfData)
       {
           string[] fields = par.ReadFields();
           foreach (string field in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(field);
           }
      }  
      par.Close();
    }

   public void RunReadCSVFile(string fn, string delim = "|")
   {
        //var f = ReadCSVFile(@"C:\Temp\car1.txt");
        //f.Load();
        FileName = fn;
        Delimiter = delim;
        Load();

    }

       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player plr = new Player("First","Last","Middle",DateTime.Now,"nat",'G');
            plr.RunReadCSVFile(@"C:\temp\car1.txt");

        }
```

Comment: I posted the edit.  It originally came through as from anonymous user because I wasn't logged in.

Comment: Why would you change the method Load to `private`?

Comment: In the scenario I presented, it does not need to be public because it is called from the instance method ReadCSVFile.

Comment: What to do if I want to display the rows like this: `1|Mariuss|Luka|Thygesen|1986-07-25|NAURU|NR`?
Now I'm just getting it word by word, which results in a (very) long list

Comment: *for a file that contains 100 rows on my computer. And it doesn't display all the lines

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: I will post in a different question

Answer (score 1):

You try to use `ReadCVSFile` like it was a class

```
var f = new ReadCSVFile(@"C:\Temp\car1.txt");
f.Load();
```

but there is no class `ReadCVSFile`.

Also this line indicates you want to use a class

```
public ReadCVSFile(string filename, string delim = "|") {
}
```

as this is the structure of a constructor.

But you don't define class `ReadCVSFile` anywhere.

I would suggest something like this

```
class Player {
    //player properties
    // ...

    public Player(...) { ... }
    public string ToString() { ...}
} //end of class player 


class ReadCVSFile {

    private List<string> content = new List<string>();
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Delimiter { get; set; }
    public ReadCSVFile(string fn, string delim = "|")
    {
        FileName = fn;
        Delimiter = delim;
    }

    public void Load() { ...}

    static void RunReadCSVFile()
    {
        var f = new ReadCSVFile(@"C:\Temp\car1.txt");
        f.Load();
    }
}
```

You code does not make clear the role of the player class here? Should the cvs file contain the players?

Answer (score 0):

Method `ReadCSVFile`must have a return type associated, if method doesn't return anything then mark it as `void` . *void specifies that the method doesn't return a value.*

Methods are declared in a class or struct by specifying the access level such as public or private, optional modifiers such as abstract or sealed, the return value, the name of the method, and any method parameters. These parts together are the signature of the method. Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) for more.

```
public void ReadCSVFile(string fn, string delim = "|")
    {
        FileName = fn;
        Delimiter = delim;
    }
```

Comment: That was that red line :-) I forgot to mention that I had an error in `static void ReadCSVFile` "the type or namespace ReadCSVFile could not be found"